# Printing intermediate tensors during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am having a custom layer and I want to print the intermediate tensors which are not linked to the returned tensor(shown in code) by `call()` method of custom layer. The code I used is:

```py
class Similarity(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):    
        super(Similarity, self).__init__()
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
#         self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((16,self.num1, 1)), trainable=False)    
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(Similarity, self).build((None, self.num1, 1))
            
    
    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        # Just pass the received mask from previous layer, to the next layer or 
        # manipulate it if this layer changes the shape of the input
        return mask
        
    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        print(">>", type(inputs), inputs.shape, inputs)

        normalized = tf.nn.l2_normalize(inputs, axis = 2)
        print("norm", normalized)
        # multiply row i with row j using transpose
        # element wise product
        similarity = tf.matmul(normalized, normalized,
                         adjoint_b = True # transpose second matrix
                         )
    
        print("SIM", similarity)
        
        z=tf.linalg.band_part(similarity, 0, -1)*3 + tf.linalg.band_part(similarity, -1, 0)*2 - tf.linalg.band_part(similarity,0,0)*6 + tf.linalg.band_part(similarity,0,0)
#         z = K.print_tensor(tf.reduce_sum(z, 2, keepdims=True))
        z = tf.reduce_sum(z, 2, keepdims=True)
    
        z = tf.argsort(z)                # <----------- METHOD2: Reassigned the Z to the tensor I want to print temporarily
        z = K.print_tensor(z)
        print(z)
    
        z=tf.linalg.band_part(similarity, 0, -1)*3 + tf.linalg.band_part(similarity, -1, 0)*2 - tf.linalg.band_part(similarity,0,0)*6 + tf.linalg.band_part(similarity,0,0)

        z = K.print_tensor(tf.reduce_sum(z, 2, keepdims=True)) #<------------- THIS LINE WORKS/PRINTS AS Z is returned
        # z = tf.reduce_sum(z, 2, keepdims=True)
        
        
        @tf.function                             
                                              #<------------- METHOD1: Want to print RANKT tensor but this DID NOT WORKED
        def f(z):
            rankt = K.print_tensor(tf.argsort(z))
#             rankt = tf.reshape(rankt, (-1, self.num1))
#             rankt = K.print_tensor(rankt)
            return rankt
        
        pt = f(z)
        
        return z               # <--------- The returned tensor
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        print("IS", (None, self.num1, 1))
        return (None, self.num1, 1)
```

To be more clear,

I  used `method1` in which I used `@tf.function` to print `rankt` tensor but it didn't worked.

Secondly, in `method2`, I reassigned `z`(returned tensor after `call()`) temporarily, so that it's executed in `backprop` and I get the printed values. After this I reassigned `z` to original opertaions

**To summarize it I don't want value of `z` but I want to print value of some variable which is depended upon `z` but I am not able to print any variable other than `z`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searhed a lot but I couldn't find anything to print intermediate tenosors. I turns out that we could only print the tensors which are linked to the exectuted tensor (here `z`). So what I did was, I printed `z` using `K.print_tensor()` and then, later on, used that tensor (obviously now in list form) to perform my computation (was side computation, not to be implemented in logic)

Answer (score 0):

There is [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) function for this.

In the eager mode, it returns nothing and just prints the tensors. When used during computation graph building, it returns TF operators that do identity and print the tensor values as a side-effect.

Comment: how can I run tf.print in eager mode during training?

Comment: Can you give some sample code that demonstrates this? I have tried using `tf.print()` in graph building and it does not get executed.